# Trying to create picklist field in Exact target by using AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can I create a picklist field, where for example for Education I'd like to have the following values:

- B.tech
- M.tech
- MCA
- MBA

```
    %%[    
            set @fname = RequestParameter("Firstname")
            set @lname = RequestParameter("Lastname")
            set @email = RequestParameter("Email")
            set @Education=RequestParameter("Education")
            InsertData("AMPKSL","Firstname",@fname,"Lastname",@lname,"Email",@email,"Education",@Education)    
    ]%%
```

This is my landing page in ET

Comment: Please provide more information on your request and show any code you have used so far or tell us about what you have tried so far. See here for help on forming a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways - but going off your request in the title, the pure AMPScript way would be to use the [BuildOptionLIst(1,2,3)](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/buildoptionlist2/#BuildOptionList) function

Parameter 1 - String - Variable used to determine which option becomes selected by default
Parameter 2 - String - Value of first option on the list
Parameter 3 - String - Presentation name of first option on the list

Sample:
 `%%=BuildOptionList(AttribA, "1", "One", "2", "Two", "3", "Three")=%%`

Output:

```
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I will try with this and get back to you

Comment: html>
<body>
<form  method="post" action="  http://pages.S7.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e730a3be2b9ff48e6e054684151c61a81138312cff5fd8fe617 ">


        FirstName:<input type="text" name="Firstname"  /></br>
 LastName: <input type="text" name="Lastname" /></br>
 Email:    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="email" name="Email" /></br>
 Education:        </br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit"/></br>
        
    </form>
       </body>
</html>
this is my form page here i want to make that picklist